# Python regex not matching when regex101 shows otherwise

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I'm trying to match the following pattern:

`...hello world...foo...bar...` where "." could be any character. Also, it should NOT contain words `alice` and `bob`.

This is what I've tried: `pattern = r'^(?!.*(alice|bob)).*hello world.*foo.*bar'` and I tested it on regex101.com and it works, but when I tried `re.findall(pattern, "hello world, this is foo and bar")`, it shows no match.

I'm pretty new to regex and couldn't figure out where is wrong, thanks for all helps in advance!

Comment: Can you give a link showing how this works on regex101? https://regex101.com/r/T6URgt/1 This is whet I'm seeing.

Comment: @axe319 sorry there was a type in my original question, it's .*hello world rather than *.hello world, updated just now

Comment: @axe319 https://regex101.com/r/T6URgt/2

Comment: Try enclosing your pattern in parentheses. https://regex101.com/r/T6URgt/3

Comment: Thank you it seems to work now! Any idea why it behaves this way?

Comment: I'll add it as answer.

Comment: Or use a non capture group: `(?:alice|bob)`

Answer (score 1):

`re.findall` either returns a list of all capturing groups if there are any. If not it returns the entire match.

In your example `(alice|bob)` is a capturing group, even if it's within a negative lookahead. That's why it's returning a `list` with an empty string.
Adding parentheses around the entire pattern makes it your first capturing group. And therefore will return as the first element in your list.

There are alternative ways to get around this. You could remove your `(alice|bob)` capturing group and replace it with `.*alice|.*bob)` which is the same thing without the capturing group.

Full Code:

```
import re

pattern = r'^(?!.*alice|.*bob).*hello world.*foo.*bar'
print(re.findall(pattern, 'hello world, this is foo and bar'))
```

Comment: There's also the *non-capturing group*: `(?:alice|bob)`